# How to find the list of all occupation with male and female domiance using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have to list the total number of males and females per occupation, and to check if the occupation is male or female dominated.

Here is the dataframe:

```
user_id age sex occupation  zip_code
0   1   24  M   technician  85711
1   2   53  F   other       94043
2   3   23  M   writer      32067
3   4   24  M   technician  43537
4   5   33  F   other       15213
```

The output should be like:

```
Occupation Male Female Difference Domination (male or female dominated)
.           .    .      .           .           
.           .    .      .           .           
.           .    .      .           .
```

I have tried this so far:

```
movie_df2.groupby(['sex','occupation']).count()
```

But it doesn't work. Would love any help.

EDIT: 
I further did:

```
df3 = movie_df2[['sex','occupation']]
df3.head()
```

and got:

```
sex occupation
0   M   technician
1   F   other
2   M   writer
3   M   technician
4   F   other
```

further I did `df3.groupby(['occupation','sex']).count().head()`

and got:

```
occupation     sex
administrator   F
                M
  artist        F
                M
   doctor       M
```

where do I go from here? now I require the count of males and females for each occupation.

Comment: When you rearrange your columns in he groupby you should get the sex count per occupation ```movie_df2 = movie_df2.groupby(['occupation','sex']).count()```

Comment: It also gives me user_id age zip_code in the count. I want the output in the format as mentioned in the question, and I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
a = df.groupby(['occupation','sex']).size().reset_index(name='counts').pivot(index='occupation', columns='sex').fillna(0)
a['Diff'] = a['counts', 'M'] - a['counts', 'F']
a['Domination'] = np.where(a['Diff'] > 0, "Male","Female")
a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def dominationF(df):
    mcount = df[df['sex'] == 'M'].shape[0]
    fcount = df[df['sex'] == 'F'].shape[0]

    if mcount > fcount:
        domination = 'male'
    else:
        domination = 'female'

    diff = mcount - fcount

    return mcount, fcount, diff, domination


finalDF = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Occupation', 'Male', 'Female', 'Diff', 'Domination'],
                  index = range(len(df_61619957['occupation'].unique())))  

i = 0
for group, data in df.groupby(['occupation']):
    mcount1, fcount1, diff1, domination1 = dominationF(data)
    finalDF.iloc[i] = [group, mcount1, fcount1, diff1, domination1]
    i = i + 1


finalDF
```

Here is the finalDF

```
    Occupation      Male    Female  Diff    Domination
   0    other       0       2       -2      female
   1    technician  2       0       2        male
   2    writer      1       0       1       male
```